# Why does target="_blank" break links in snippets?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-snippets

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655490/anchor-tag-is-not-working-on-image-hover-effect), which although somewhat low quality, demonstrated a weird behaviour with StackSnippets:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">Test (broken)</a><br>
<a href="https://example.com/">Test without target="blank" (works)</a>
```

`target="_blank"` stops the link from working. I'm running `Google Chrome 50.0.2661.102` on `Mac OS X 10.11`. I have the same issue on `Safari 9.1.11` as well.

Comment: The link is neutered without an error. This looks a lot like a sandboxing / security feature to prevent malicious users from attempting fishing through new browser windows.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Stack Snippets are run inside a sandboxed iframe which only allows modals and scripts, and does not allow access to the top navigation. So anything but _self on a link will not work because it cannot open the link that way.

Unless you have a very good reason to allow opening links in other ways via the snippets, it should remain sandboxed this way. I can't imagine many scenarios where a link actually taking you somewhere from the snippet itself would be useful. They exist to demonstrate a problem, and following links to other places doesn't really help demonstrate any problems.

Comment: "I can't imagine many scenarios where a link actually taking you somewhere from the snippet itself would be useful." well, any questions about `target="_blank"` or their appropriate use, such as on `<a>` and `<form>` elements, or any calls to `window.open` in JavaScript. I've seen plenty of questions that would have benefitted from a working example. That said, I don't think they're common enough to warrant changing the sandboxing. There are other ways of showing those particular demos in action.

Comment: Of course you can't imagine it

Answer (score -3):

StackOverflow snippets are not actually breaking your links. Snippets are iframes loading within a parent stackoverflow page. So by default you will not be able to create a new parent tab by clicking on a link from an iframe.

However you will be able to change this behaviour on your webpage. If you are trying to click on a link within an iframe and still be able to create a new blank window, then do this:

First add this to the  of your parent page:

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

You can then just add an anchor with target=_blank and it will open in a new blank tab when you click on it. Voila!

Comment: What does this add that the official answer from a member of the Stack Overflow team covers?

Comment: It is helpful to know how to use `target="_blank"` in an actual web page. Sometimes code from a snippet, or similar code, will eventually be used in production; [what happens in Stack Snippets doesn't necessarily stay in Stack Snippets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Happens_in_Vegas).